# Crystal Reports Cross-Tab, Grouping by Database Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports, crosstab

Currently I have a cross tab in my report, reading all of the products in I wish to display. They are already grouped under their relevant customer who is associated with them, however I want to add a further grouping to distinguish between different types of products.

For example, I currently have;

```
CustomerName

Total
Product Code1     3     24     72
Product Code2     3     24     72
Product Code3     3     24     72
```

However I wish to have;

```
CustomerName

Total

Red Products
Product Code1     3     24     72
Product Code2     3     24     72

Blue Products
Product Code3     3     24     72
```

I have the Group By identifier in my database, is it possible to complete this second group in the cross tab? Also how should I go about it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible: in Cross Tab Expert, choose 2 rows and set Grouping Options.

Appearence won't be as desired, but you can rotate 1st column text 90° if you like.

```
CustomerName

Total


Red Products  Product Code1     3     24     72
              Product Code2     3     24     72

Blue Products Product Code3     3     24     72
```